# Rails render or redirect_to with PATCH request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I got some problem with the PATCH request.

I want to `PATCH "/activities/7/mans"` and `update` some value
but if updated value not valid then how could I redirect it to `:new` ?

Here's the rails server log

```
Started PATCH "/activities/7/mans" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-04 12:55:58 +0800
Processing by MansController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"Qnn/N9yWMtxAwA9N+br5r+mMvPdoY4fBJaI3sCYnObY=","activity_id"=>"7"}
```

When I use render new after update
I always got `{GET} not {PATCH}`

```
Started GET "/activities/7/mans" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-04 12:58:56 +0800
Processing by MansController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"activity_id"=>"7"}
```

here is route.rb setting

```
resources :activities do
  resources :mans, :only => [:index ,:create] do
    collection do
      patch :new
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my controller action

```
  def new
    @activity = Activity.find_by_id(params[:activity_id])
    @man= Man.new
  end

  def create
    @man = Man.new(man_params)
    if @man.age <20
      redirect_to :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show your controller action? It most likely has to do with how you made the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a validation error it's common not to redirect but to respond with some html at once:

```
  def create
    @man = Man.new(man_params)
    if @man.save # validation for age < 20 should be in the model
      redirect_to my_redirect_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

and exactly the same for `update` action which you didn't provide in the question:

```
  def update
    @man = Man.find(man_params[:id])
    if @man.update_attributes(man_params) # validation for age < 20 should be in the model
      redirect_to my_redirect_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

This way you can print any validation errors in the view using `@man.errors`.

In order this to work you should have `edit` (and `update` of course) action in the controller and modify routes as follows (if you don't need `show` and `destroy` actions):

```
resources :activities do
  resources :mans, :except => [:show, :destroy]
end
```